# How send in form 'POST' JSON structure?

Tags: html, json, forms

How I need for  html to send in POST request such structure:

`[{"applicationUUID":"a61a0a0a-c2ff-4238-ab0e-69ae8898a00b","applicationName":"SSM - Incident Management","hasSDF":true,"hasSLA":true},{"applicationUUID":"9c3e7a8a-dace-469d-a275-c804dfa44a41","applicationName":"SSM - Change Management","hasSDF":false,"hasSLA":true},{"applicationUUID":"fcd84a6b-73fe-453a-965a-c841ae6df170","applicationName":"SSM - Problem Management","hasSDF":false,"hasSLA":true}]`

How to send like a variable string?

Comment: is form data send by ajax?

Comment: @Girish — Given the question doesn't mention JavaScript at all, it doesn't seem likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't". The only HTML mechanism for making POST requests is a form, which supports [three encoding methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-enctype); JSON isn't one of them. A specification for [JSON Forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/) has been proposed, but browser support is weak (probably non-existent) and the data structure doesn't match the one you want.

The only way to send the data from the browser would be to use JavaScript. You'll need to gather the data, create your arrays and objects, [convert them to JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), then [make the request using XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), while being sure to [set the correct content-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers).

Answer (score 0):

The given data formData is JSON. You can use AJAX to send JSON data.

```
var formData = [
{
     "applicationUUID":"a61a0a0a-c2ff-4238-ab0e-69ae8898a00b",
     "applicationName":"SSM - Incident Management",
     "hasSDF":true,
     "hasSLA":true
},
{
     "applicationUUID":"9c3e7a8a-dace-469d-a275-c804dfa44a41",
     "applicationName":"SSM - Change Management",
     "hasSDF":false,
     "hasSLA":true
},
{
     "applicationUUID":"fcd84a6b-73fe-453a-965a-c841ae6df170",
     "applicationName":"SSM - Problem Management",
     "hasSDF":false,
     "hasSLA":true
}];

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://example.com:6060/testAjax/', // Target URL
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(formData)
});
```